# Tagged AWS resources in API

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, filter, tags

I need to get all the resources specific to the tag using API. Similar option is available in AWS Config console but i am unable to find in API, wherein resource inventory page we can specify the tag and get all the resource specific to that tag.

Comment: Hi,I am able to get the value through EC2 Describe tags for all ec2 resources but not for RDS resources.

Comment: Please let me know whether is there any api where i can able to find all the resource for specific tag

Answer (score 0):

There is no single command to get all resources.

Each service has it's own way to list resources by tag. Some services, such as EC2 support listing of all resources based on tag values.

For example, use `describe-tags` with a tag filter:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --region us-east-1 \
  --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=Test
```

But the results are limited to EC2 resources.

Other services, such as RDS, does not support listing of resources based on tag values. Instead, you need to retrieve all resources, then retrieve the tags for those resources, then filter yourself.

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --region us-east-1 \
  --query 'DBInstances[*].DBInstanceIdentifier'
```

then for each resource, you need to call `list-tags-for-resource` to get the tags:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --region us-east-1 \
  --resource-name arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:<account number>:db:<db instance id>
```

In the end, you'll need to:

1. Use each service's methods for each resource type to list the resources, and
2. Repeat this in each region you care about.

Example:

```
* us-east-1
  * EC2
    * describe-tags
  * RDS
    * describe-db-instances
      * list-tags-for-resource
    * describe-db-snapshots
      * list-tags-for-resource
* us-west-1
  * EC2
    * describe-tags
  * RDS
    * describe-db-instances
      * list-tags-for-resource
    * describe-db-snapshots
      * list-tags-for-resource
```

... etc.

Comment: I am able to get all the resources that comes under EC2 (VPC, Volume, Snapshot, subnet, security groups etc) using "aws ec2 describe-tags" command but for RDS i need a similar command to take all resources for specific tag. Please let me know if there any options to take RDS resource values.

Comment: I forgot about `describe-tags`. I have updated my answer. I have also clarified the information regarding RDS.

Comment: I appears you can do this with AWS CLI but not and AWS Java API.  You have to: 1) get all DB Instances then 2) list the tags.  I wish there were a way to filter on only DBs that have a specific tag (i.e. "dev", "test", "prod").